# Ignore specific symbol in cells before calculating the average of the column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a column of data in `B7:B30`:

```
<0.0012
<0.0013
<0.0014
<0.0015
```

And so on...

I want the average of these cells to appear in cell `B31`. But Excel sees the `<` symbol in each cell and won't return a value. I need the lesser than symbol to remain in each cell.

Is this possible?

Comment: I assume that the data type of the data is a string, not a number... correct? If so, why are you expecting the average of a string to be something meaningful?  How are you requesting the mean value (`average(B7:B30)`? or something else?)?

Comment: I find it is usually best to add a new column (even if it's hidden) that parses the value out and then do math on that column.

Comment: Have you considered stripping out the *less than* symbol so you have a column of true numbers then adding the *less than* symbol back in with a custom number format of "<"0.0000 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=SUM(VALUE((SUBSTITUTE(B7:B30,"<",""))))/COUNTA(B7:B30)
```

with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Will fail if there are any blanks in the range.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an extra level of processing to parse the text and convert the result to an actual number with `SUMPRODUCT()`.

To sum the numbers:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A1:A4,2,99))
```

To count the numbers:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(--MID(A1:A4,2,99)))
```

To average the numbers:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A1:A4,2,99))/SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(--MID(A1:A4,2,99)))
```

`SUMPRODUCT()` chokes pretty quickly when attempting to pare down text like *abc* into a number. Additional error control may be possible but valid data is the best route. Limit the ranges to what is on your worksheet and avoid full column range references like A:A.